# Error in sql query of a csv dataset in ms excel

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlwings

I am trying to do an sql query  on a csv file in ms excel with python xlwings library in vs code.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('MYTestDB.csv')

wb = xw.Book()

sheet = wb.sheets[0]
sheet.range('A1').options(pd.DataFrame, index = False).value = df

sql_query = " SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE height < 151 "

data_range = sheet.range('A1').expand('table')
data_df = data_range.options(pd.DataFrame).value
result = data_df.query(sql_query)

result_sheet = wb.sheets.add('QueryResult')
result_sheet.range('A1').value = result
```

Encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3550 in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) 
Cell In[6], line 3 result = data_df.query(sql_query)
 
File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4599 in query res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs) 

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4725 in eval return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs) 

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\eval.py:336 in eval parsed_expr = Expr(expr, engine=engine, parser=parser, env=env) 

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py:808 in __init__ self.terms = self.parse()

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py:827 in parse return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py:407 in visit raise e 

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py:403 in visit node = ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse(clean)) 

File c:\Users\Niyi Akinjeji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ast.py:50 in parse return compile(source, filename, mode, flags, 

File <unknown>:1 
     SELECT *FROM [Sheet1 $]WHERE height <151 
                          ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Expectation:**
I expect that a new sheet named "QueryResult" will open up in excel beside Sheet1 that contain the    csv data table. But instead it displays above errors.

Comment: Isn't `data_df` a Pandas dataframe? The [DataFrame.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function doesn't accept SQL queries. You could use `data_df.query('height < 151)` or `data_df.loc[data_df['height'] < 151]`